# Sublime Text 3 - Autocomplete HTML Comments

Tags: macos, autocomplete, comments, sublimetext3

How can I modify my preferences so that Sublime Text 3 will recognize 
`<!` as the beginning of a comment, which upon pressing `enter`, will complete it to be `<!---->`? Essentially I'm trying to get ST3 to recognize `<!` the same way it recognizes the beginning of an HTML tag e.g. `<p`, which upon pressing enter gets completed to be `<p></p>`

From what I've been able to tell, I can't do this directly through ST3's preferences. What file do I have to modify to do this?

Thanks guys.

Comment: Look at how custom snippets are made and managed.

Comment: @waraker Where are the custom snippets located? I've tried looking for them but can't find them. Do you know?

Comment: What platform are you on @tarchuletta?

Comment: @waraker I'm using a Mac running El Capitan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I figured it out! I couldn't get `<!` to be recognized in the tab completion, so I decided to make it `<cm` as a shorthand for 'comment'. Either way, now when I type `<cm` and press `tab`, it autocompletes to be `<!---->` and places the cursor between the two middle hyphens. Also, I'm using Sublime Text 3, Version 3, Build 3143.

**After showing this to a friend, I realized that you can just press `CMD+/` to do this exact same thing without editing any files, but I thought I'd share this anyway because it's a way to create your own custom tab completions.**

1. Open Finder>Applications
2. Right click on Sublime Text>Show Package Contents
3. Go to `Contents>MacOS>Packages` and open `HTML.sublime-package`

   (I used [BBedit](https://www.barebones.com/support/bbedit/updates.html) to open the file)
4. Select `html_completions.py`
5. Search for `default_list += ([`
6. Add `('cm\tTag', '!--$0-->'),` to the top of list right above

   `('a\tTag', 'a href=\"$1\">$0</a>'),`

   [(Here's an image of the code to edit.)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmNFe.png)
7. Save the file.
8. If Sublime Text is running, close out, quit it, then reopen it. Otherwise, just open it.
9. Save the current blank text window as an `.html`
10. Now if you type `<cm` and press `Tab`, it will tab complete and become `<!---->` and will place your cursor right in the middle of the two middle hyphens.
11. To create your own, change the `cm` and `!--$0-->` found in `('cm\tTag', '!--$0-->'),` to anything that you want, e.g.

    `('hello\tTag', 'yo diggity>'),`

    which returns

    `<yo diggity>`

BUT, like I said above, **the easiest way to comment something out is just to press `CMD+/`.**